# Probabilities of a Bernoulli trials success runs.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a list of Bernoulli trails with 1 = success and 0 = failure and I am maintaining a consecutive count of successive runs.
For example:

List = $0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 $

Consecutive success runs count result = $\{1: 2, 2: 1\}$

where key is success run, and value is the count of that success run

Another example to clarify:

List = $0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 $

Consecutive success runs count result = $\{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1\}$

there are two times where the success run has the count $2$, hence the value $2:2$

My question is, given a list of Bernoulli trials, how would we calculate the probability of observing at least one success run of length '$k$'.
So for the above example $(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)$, what's the probability of observing at least one success run of length $(k = 2,$ i.e finding $1,1)$.

Kindly help solving for one list, and then generalize it on $n$ list, where $n$ would be the number of lists (more than $1$) and finding the probability of at least one success run of length '$k$'.

Thank you so much

Comment: By a "success run of length $k$" do you mean length exactly $k$, or at least $k$?

Comment: exactly k, k = 2, or k = 3 etc. So for k = 3, meaning the probability of atleast finding one `1, 1, 1` in the list.

Comment: Some care is needed with wording here. For example, $1,1,1$ is found twice in the list $1,1,1,1$, but of course neither time is the success run of length *exactly* three.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In the second example:  0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1

```
1 - came one time, 
1,1 - came two times, 
1, 1, 1 - came one times, 

hence {1:1,2:2,3:1}
```

successful run is considered for a subsequence with all ones.

Comment: if there's a list like [1, 1, 1, 1], just as an example, then the output would be {4:1}

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the success probability of each Bernoulli trials - assuming that all trials are i.i.d.

Note that in a sequence of $n$ trials, there are $n - k + 1$ possible locations to  place a success run of length $k$ - the success run can begin at the trial  $1, 2, \ldots, n - k + 1$

Denote $S_i$ be the event that a success run of exactly length $k$ begin at the trial $i$.

Since we require the length of the success to be $k$, the event $S_i$ not only require the $k$ trials in the specific location - from the $i$-th trial until the $(i+k-1)$-th trial to be success trials, it also require the two trials before and after the run, namely $(i-1)$-th and $(i+k)$-th trial respectively to be fail trial.

The success run at the boundary location - begins at the $1$st trial and $n-k+1$ is different from the interior runs as there is no trial outside the boundary - they only require one fail trial.

Therefore
$$ P(S_i) = \begin{cases} p^k(1-p)^2 & \text{if} & i = 2, 3, \ldots, n - k \\ p^k(1-p) & \text{if} & i = 1, n-k+1 \end{cases}$$

The required event of havivg at least one success run is the union of those events $S_i$, which can be further expanded via inclusion-exclusion principle:

$$ P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-k+1} S_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} P(S_i) - \sum_{i \neq j} P(S_i \cap S_j) + \ldots 
+ (-1)^{n-k}P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-k+1} S_i \right)$$

For the simple case of $k \leq n \leq 2k$, there is no room to place two success run of length $k$.
Therefore all $S_i \cap S_j = \varnothing$, i.e. all the $S_i$ are mutually exclusive and thus all the latter terms are vanished except the first term:
$$ \begin{align} 
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-k+1} S_i \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1} P(S_i) \\
&= (n-k-1)p^k(1-p)^2 + 2p^k(1-p) \\
&= [(n-k-1)(1-p)+2]p^k(1-p)
\end{align} $$

For larger $n$, we will need to consider multiple run cases. The good thing is two success run is non-overlapping by the requirement of exact length. They at most overlap the failure trials at the end which we included in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n$ be the probability of not getting any success run of length $k$ by conditioning on the number of leading $1$'s in the sequence we get:

$$p_n = \frac{1}{2}p_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{4}p_{n - 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2 ^ k}p_{n - k} \forall \space n \ge k$$

i.e. if you have a zero in the first place then it suffices for other $n - 1$ trials to not have $k$ consecutive successes, if you have a one in first place and a zero in second place it suffices for the next $n - 2$ trials not to have any $k$ consecutive successes, etc.

with the recursion base of $p_n = 2 ^ n$ for any $n \le k - 1$. The probability of getting at least one success run of length $k$ can be computed by taking the complement event.